# How can I center align text within div horizontally?

Tags: css

This may be the stupid question,but I can't figure it out how to get this.

edit: I just want to center only text horizontally not the image and the image must be remain baseline to the text

`<div>
<img style="width:30px;height:60px;vertical-align:bottom;display: inline" src="http://placekitten.com/100">
   <span style="text-align:center;">This won't work.</span>
</div>`

http://jsfiddle.net/Hyx5n/39/

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of the `span` and apply `style="text-align:center;"` to the `div` instead.

Answer (score 0):

It you need to center it horizontally then use this

```
div {
  text-align: center;
}
```

Have a look here! :) http://jsfiddle.net/afzaal_ahmad_zeeshan/Hyx5n/41/

This way, all the elements inside the `div` (and not only the text) will be placed in the center. This way, you'll get the image in the center.

Answer (score 0):

Building on Afzaal Ahmad Zeeshan's answer...

Put the text between 2 equal images. Set `text-align:center` on the containing div. This centers the image-text-image as a group.

Then hide the second image.

HTML:

```
<div>
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/100">
    This works now.
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/100" class="cannot-see-me">
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div {
    text-align: center;
}

img {
    width:30px;
    height:60px;
}

.cannot-see-me {
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

This works because `visibility:hidden` makes an element invisible, but it still takes up space on the page. So use that here instead of `display:none`.

Comment: Also: `<img>` is displayed inline by default and [vertical-align is baseline by default](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align), so those don't need to be specified. And I'd agree with Adam McElroy regarding the `<span>` tags. They're only needed if you wish to apply more styles to the text.

Answer (score -1):

change `vertical-align:bottom` to `vertical-align:middle` and set `text-align:center` to `<div>`

[**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Hyx5n/42/)

```
<div style="text-align:center">
   <img style="width:30px;height:60px;
vertical-align:middle;display: inline" src="http://placekitten.com/100">
   <span style="text-align:center;">This won't work.</span>
</div>
```